# How to link LuaSQL in a C++ application?

Tags: scripting, lua, require, luasql

My script runs fine when I execute it from outside the application (terminal), but when its called from inside the C++ application it shuts down in the require("luasql.mysql") call.

Can anyone help?

Comment: the problem is solved, the package.cpath was wrong in the application. so the require function couldn't find it.

thanks anyway.

Comment: please answer your own question and accept the answer since you have solved the problem since asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package.cpath and package.path must be set inside the script to load the modules that are installed. So package.cpath must have the folders that lua can check for the clibs to load them, and the same for package.path, but this time to load lua modules or files.